# Javascript date to xs:dateTime

Tags: javascript, xml, date, datetime

Is there a simple way to convert standard Javascript date format to xs:dateTime

So I have a date value (new Date()) and I need in the format: 2015-01-16T20:26:53.974+03:00

so

> Fri Jan 16 2015 22:26:53 GMT+0500 (Ekaterinburg Standard Time) ->
>   2015-01-16T20:26:53.974+03:00

It strange but cound't find simple solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is the same as the ISO date format

```js
var date = new Date();
var formatted = date.toISOString();
```

Comment: Great, the only it doesn't contain time zone '+03:00'

Comment: Ahhh shoot, sorry. You are right. Basically you want the following format string
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sss
The ISO standard uses
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
Which removes timezone and assumes UTC.

without a good formatter library you have to do it manually

x.getFullYear() + "-" + (x.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + x.getDate() + "T" + x.getHours() + ":" + x.getMinutes() + ":" + x.getSeconds() + ":" + x.getMilliseconds() + "+" + (x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) + ":00"

Comment: Or another option. Combine the two approaches. Var x = new Date(). var formatted = x.toISOString(). formatted += "+" + (x.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) + ":00"