# Javascript date with xs:dateTime

Tags: javascript, soap

Is there a simple way to convert standard JavaScript date format to XS:date Time

So I have a date value (new Date()) and I need in the format: 2021-06-04T13:36:00.000+05:00

It strange but could not  find simple solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript date to xs:dateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990311/javascript-date-to-xsdatetime)

Comment: Any code in java script.

Answer (score 0):

I think this worked for you

```js
var date = new Date();
var formattedDate = date.toISOString() + "+" +(date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) + ":00"
console.log(formattedDate)
```